# Python Tree / Dict

Tags: python

I am working on a project were I would like to  create a Python `dict` subclass and then work with it later. I need to assign a `self.key` attribute in the `__init__` and I am not sure the best way to do this.

This is what I have so far.

```
Class GoDown(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.key = dict.keys() # I know this is incorrect this is where I am stuck

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = GoDown(d=1)
```

In the example above I want `t.key` to equal `'d'`. I just don't know the best way to do this with a `dict` subclass.

Comment: ...what? Do you mean afterwards `t.key == 'd'` should be `True`? What should happen to the `1`? Or do you mean `t.key == 1`, in which case what does `d` mean (why not `key=1`)?

Comment: I am going off the assumption, maybe wrong that in the above case D = key and 1 = value. I would like my self.key to equal ' D'.

Comment: What if more than one keyword argument is passed in? What about positional arguments? What exactly are you trying to achieve (and what precisely is `GoDown` supposed to add over a vanilla `dict`)?

Comment: possibly `self.key = kw.keys()[0]` then (no need to create a new dict). What should you do with the value, though?

Comment: to tell you the truth I am spinning my wheels here. I could limit it to just a key, value in the __init__. I would like to look at later items added to the dict and see if it is before or after this intial self.key

Comment: Well we can't really help if you don't explain what you're trying to do; this could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The minimal fix is what **njzk2** suggests, but note that dictionaries aren't ordered (so what does *"before or after"* mean?), so you need to decide what (if anything) e.g. `GoDown(d=1, t=2)` should do.

Comment: I can't quite understand what it is that you want to do.  Do you want to create a `dict` subclass that **requires** that `key` be provided, as well as any other initial values?  Do you want to create a `dict` subclass that will **only** allow you to provide `key` when the `dict` is initially created?  Am I way far off base?  Why would you store the key value in `self.key` rather than `self['key']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this as follows:

```
class GoDown(dict):
    """Dictionary with an additional attribute recording the initial key."""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if len(kwargs) != 1:
            raise TypeError("Exacly one keyword argument required.")
        super(GoDown, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.key = kwargs.keys()[0]
```

This prevents users from passing additional positional or keyword arguments by removing `*args` and checking the length of `kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use a ready-to-use tree-structure
https://github.com/caesar0301/pyTree

pyTree also provides the posibility visualizing the tree:

```
Harry[harry]
|___ Jane[jane]
|    |___ Diane[diane]
|         |___ George[george]
|              |___ Jill[jill]
|         |___ Mary[mary]
|    |___ Mark[mark]
|___ Bill[bill]
```